# JSON content from file via Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, json-simple

My program parse JSON from file where is saved unstructured content of this json adress.

Unstructured json format from file json.txt:
`{"total":3307,"watershed":100,"maxPage":5,"search":"http://10.103.80.149:3312/bin/sp?app=pinglun&outfmt=json&seek_timeout=400&gmt_create=1465228800~&validfeedback=1&item_id=538236063692&rate=1&layer_quota=500000&status=0,-1&order=algo_sort:des&s=0&n=20&is_wireless=0&user_id=0&utd_id=ba3290d86b9fdcd927e8ae83fde1ee64&is_click_sku=0","currentPageNum":1,"comments":[{"auction":{"title":"","thumbnail":""....`

For better view in structured form:

```
{
  "total": 3307,
  "watershed": 100,
  "maxPage": 5,
  "search": "http://10.103.80.162:3312/bin/sp?app=pinglun&outfmt=json&seek_timeout=400&gmt_create=1465228800~&validfeedback=1&item_id=538236063692&rate=1&layer_quota=500000&status=0,-1&order=algo_sort:des&s=0&n=20&is_wireless=0&user_id=0&is_click_sku=0",
  "currentPageNum": 1,
  "comments": [
    {
      "auction": {
        "title": "",
        "thumbnail": "",
        "aucNumId": "538236063692",
        "link": "//item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=538236063692",
        "auctionPic": "//img.alicdn.com/bao/uploaded/null_40x40.jpg",
        "sku": "机身颜色:黑色（顶级配置）[移动+联通] &nbsp套餐类型:官方标配 &nbsp存储容量:64MB &nbsp版本类型:中国大陆"
      },
      "promotionType": "活动促销 ",
      "enableSNS": false,
      "tag": "",
      "appendCanExplainable": false,
      "showCuIcon": true,
      "validscore": 1,
      "award": "",
      "noQna": true,
      "appendList": [
        {
          "photos": [

          ],
          "content": "老人机使用效果好，功能强大，非常值得拥有！！！",
          "vicious": "",
          "reply": null,
          "show": true,
          "dayAfterConfirm": 0,
          "appendId": 290673146633
        }
      ],
      "from": "",
      "date": "2016年11月05日 16:46",
      "dayAfterConfirm": 0,
      "bidPriceMoney": {
        "cent": 7905,
        "amount": 79.05,
        "currencyCode": "CNY",
        "centFactor": 100,
        "displayUnit": "元",
        "currency": {
          "defaultFractionDigits": 2,
          "currencyCode": "CNY",
          "symbol": "￥"
        }
      },
      "rate": "1",
      "o2oRate": null,
      "propertiesAvg": "0.0",
      "showDepositIcon": false,
      "rateId": 290589793921,
      "creditFraudRule": 0,
      "useful": 0,
      "reply": null,
      "append": {
        "photos": [

        ],
        "content": "老人机使用效果好，功能强大，非常值得拥有！！！",
        "vicious": "",

.
.
.
.}
```

And I need to parse only chinese comments in element "content" e.g.  "老人机使用效果好，功能强大，非常值得拥有！！！", but I don't know how to works with this element in JSONArray with json-simple.

Here is example of code:

```
public class Final {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
        String jsonData = "";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String line;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("json.txt"));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonData += line + "\n";
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nFile Content: \n" + jsonData1); // displays all content
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        System.out.println("search: " + obj.getString("search"));
        System.out.println("comments: " + obj.getJSONObject("comments"));
}
}
```

Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: JSON adress:     https://rate.taobao.com/feedRateList.htm?userNumId=2023084868&auctionNumId=538236063692&siteID=1&currentPageNum=1&rateType=1&orderType=sort_weight&showContent=1&attribute=

Comment: Well, finally I solve it with:

     JSONArray comments = (JSONArray) jsonObject2.get("comments");

     System.out.println("search: " + name2);
     System.out.println("\ncomments:");
     Iterator<JSONObject> iterator2 = comments.iterator();

     while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
      JSONObject obj3 = iterator2.next();
      System.out.println("Comment: " + obj3.get("content"));
      // System.err.println("test");
     }